# if else condition in pandas with multiple column as arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "code": ['sp', 'wh', 'sp'],
    "qty": [20, 30, 10]})
```

I want to create a new column based on data from the two columns with the value the new column as the same as an existing column if a condition is met.

This is what I’ve tried:

```
df['out'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['qty']) if x['code'] == 'sp' else 0)
```

My output in this case should be:

```
df = [
   { 'code': 'sp', 'qty': 20, 'out': 20 }
   { 'code': 'wh', 'qty': 30, 'out':  0 }
   { 'code': 'sp', 'qty': 10, 'out': 10 }
]
```

Comment: On a df with 10.000 rows the solutions using `mask` and `np.where` are about 30x faster than the apply one. With 100.000 rows these solutions are ~50x faster.

Comment: Great point. I have been having serious speed issues with apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the parameter `axis=1` in the `apply()` method in order to apply the method on the columns :

```
df['out'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['qty'] if x['code'] == 'sp' else 0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's where:

```
import numpy as np
df['out'] = np.where(df['code']=='sp', df['qty'], 0)
```

Comment: It's slightly faster when you use `df['code'].eq('sp')`

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it using mask

```
# mask the qty as zero when code is not 'sp'

df['out']=df['qty'].mask(df['code'].ne('sp'), 0)
df
```

```
code    qty     out
0   sp  20  20
1   wh  30  0
2   sp  10  10
```